# ngShow on value selected?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I would like to display a div only when a specific value is selected (i.e. `special` ). I've tried the following but it doesn't work. Any hint how I can fix it ?

```
<select 
 ng-change="timeline.selectNote()" ng-model="timeline.selectedNote" ng-options="opt as opt.NoteContent for opt in timeline.noteOptions" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <option value="">-- select a note --</option>
</select>


<div class="select-element animate-hide" ng-show="timeline.selectedNote=='special'">
```

Comment: Post your Javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ngOptions is using `opt` as the select value (because of `opt as ...`), `timeline.selectedNote` is the entire noteOption object. Assuming the value you are checking to be equal to 'special' is `NoteContent`, this should work...

```
<div class="select-element animate-hide" ng-show="timeline.selectedNote.NoteContent=='special'">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can see here, I'm guessing that `timeline.selectedNote` is not `'special'`.

You can review what `timeline.selectedNote` is in the view by using `{{ timeline }}` and make sure that the correct value is selected.

Though, I suspect that this behavior is happening because `timeline.selectedNote` is a reference an object that you're comparing to an instance of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oqu9ib5yU69zrY3fQo2Q?p=preview) will clear it up for you. You may just want to make it available in the scope like $scope.selectedNote. But you will end up with the Object,  so you need something like.

```
{{selectedNote.yourId}}
```